# Check if value of selected checkboxes are in data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

I need to find out if the values of selected checkboxes can be found in the data-attribute of a given div.

Only if ALL the checkboxes with the values found in the data-attribute are checked, the result should be TRUE. If one or more checkboxes with values found in the data-attribute is unchecked, the result should be FALSE.

**Examples:**

```
<div id="towns" data-attribute="FRA, BER, HAM">...</div>
```

Selected Checkboxes: FRA, BER => 
Result: false

Selected Checkboxes: BER, HAM, MUC =>
Result: false

Selected Checkboxes: FRA, BER, HAM =>
Result: true

Selected Checkboxes: FRA, BER, HAM, MUC =>
Result: true

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {

  console.log($("#testdiv").data("town").split(",").indexOf($(this).val()) > -1);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Currently I only know to the result of one checkbox value. But I need to have a result of false if one of the towns presented in the data-attribute is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `for` loop that goes through every value in the `data-town` and checks if they are checked, rather than loop through every checkbox that is checked.

```js
function testChecked() {
  let arr = $("#testdiv").data("town").split(",");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!$("input[value=" + arr[i] + "]").is(":checked")) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(testChecked());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA,BER,HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh, and run that function on each checkbox click then.... makes sense!

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi Correct!

Comment: A lot of different solutions, thank you all! I do accept this answer, as it is easy to follow along and can easily used in my existing function.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all values stored in `data-town` as array. And then loop though that array. And check if the input with that values if `checked` using `every()`. And you should `split()` by `", "`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click',() => console.log(check()));
})


function check(){
  let vals = $("#testdiv").data("town").split(", ")
  return vals.every(val => $(`input[value="${val}"]`).prop('checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

#### where `${val}` does come from

:
I am using `Array.prototype.every()` and it takes a callback function. The first argument refers the element of the array. Which is `val` in this case. See [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: this works like a charme, but I don't understand where ${val} does come from

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi I have updated the code. check it and don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes:

1. First, start with a default result of `true` but set it to false if you find a checked checkbox whose value is present in the `data-town` attribute of the div.
2. Notice that there are whitespaces between values in `FRA, BER, HAM`. Since you cannot compare `_BER` (which you get by splitting the string) with `BER` (which is the value of checkbox), you need to trim those values before comparing. It can be done by appending `.map(t => t.trim())` while getting the list of towns.

Here's a working snippet.

```js
var result = true;
var towns = $("#testdiv").data("town").split(",").map(t => t.trim());
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
  if(towns.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1) {
    result = false;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect data as array and then compare two sorted arrays as strings.

Edited answer. Using `.includes()` we can check if `data-attribute` is a part of string collected from checked checkboxes.

```js
const findIfMatch = () => {
  const data = document.querySelector('#testdiv').getAttribute('data-town').split(', ').sort()
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.chb:checked')
  const values = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).map(chb => chb.value).sort()
  console.log(values.toString().includes(data.toString()))
}
```

```html
Fra <input class='chb' type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
Ber <input class='chb' type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
Ham <input class='chb' type="checkbox" value="HAM" />
Muc <input class='chb' type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>

<button onclick="findIfMatch()">Check</button>
```

Comment: This *does not* work if the user checks any boxes that are not in the `data-town`, while OP specifies it to return true regardless of extra checks.

Comment: All the condition are false.No condition have true

Comment: @prasanth It does return true if FRA, BER, and HAM are all checked, but only those.

Comment: ya right .But all checked it give false .but op need true

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Array#map` and `Array#filter`

1. Split `down` attr and you need trim after split Because its have some extra space
2. Then Map the element with return index position > -1
3. finally validate length of true value  and length of result array is `>=` town array length

```js
function check() {
  var arr = $("#testdiv").data("town").split(",").map(a => a.trim())
  var res = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function() {
    return arr.indexOf($(this).attr('value')) > -1
  }).get();
  console.log(res)
  var l = res.filter(a => a == true).length
  console.log(l >= arr.length && res.length >= arr.length)
}

$('input').change(check)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" checked/>

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example below, the iteration is just reversed: we iterate over each data-town attribute's town (note the trim).

[Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/every) checks that the specified condition "$("input[type=checkbox][value=" + t +"]:checked") selector has length > 0" is true for every items in dataTown.

If that the case we log true.

Logging occurs when changing the state of a checkbox.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    var dataTown = $("#testdiv")
                       .data("town")
                       .split(",")
                       .map(function(t) { return t.trim();});
    console.log(
        dataTown.every(
            function(t) {
                return $("input[type=checkbox][value=" + t +"]:checked").length > 0;
            }
        )
    );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of mandatory values and then use `every()` to check id every mandatory value belongs to a checked checkbox:

```js
const list = $('#testdiv').attr('data-town').split(',').map(x => x.trim());
const result = list.every(x => $(`input[type="checkbox"][value="${x}"]`).is(':checked'));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="FRA" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="BER" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="HAM" />
<input type="checkbox" value="MUC" />

<div id="testdiv" data-town="FRA, BER, HAM">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```